# Converting JSON to c# from the web

Tags: c#, json, parsing

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
   string rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("http://data.nba.net/data/10s/prod/v1/calendar.json");
   var jsonConverted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NumGameByDate>(rawJSON);
}
```

Above is my code I am attempting to retrieve the date and number of games on that date. I have achieved this with the NBA's team json data but this one is formatted differently.

```
public class NumGameByDate
{
    public _internal _internal { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string startDateCurrentSeason { get; set; }
}
```

This is my NumGameByDate class how would you suggest storing the dates and number of games. Below is an example of how the JSON looks.

```
{
"_internal": {
"pubDateTime": "2018-08-10 16:57:34.402",
"xslt": "xsl/league/schedule/marty_game_calendar.xsl",
"eventName": "_SPECIAL_ELA_EVENT_martyGameCalendar"
},
"startDate": "20171017",
"endDate": "20190410",
"startDateCurrentSeason": "20180702",
"20171017": 2,
"20171018": 11,
"20171019": 3,
"20171020": 10,
"20171021": 11,
"20171022": 3,
"20171023": 8,
"20171024": 6,
"20171025": 10,
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid (it's missing a closing brace).  They certainly didn't make it easy to parse that data.  There's an array of `Tuple<string, int>`, but that is not an array.  You are missing at least a closing brace, is there anything else that didn't copy/paste correctly?  Do they have an entry for every date, whether there are games or not (i.e., something like `"20171225": 0,`)?

Comment: That is the worst json schema I've ever seen. Looks like you just have to know what to expect for dates. Is there more? That is not valid json as you have shown.

Comment: One thing you can do is deserialize it into a `dynamic` and then walk the structure by hand.  I agree with @Crowcoder - they really don't want you to be able to parse that mess, it seems.

Comment: Yes I didn't want to paste the entire JSON because it is very long, but it includes an entry for every date from the variable 'startDate' to 'endDate' whether there are games or not. The link for JSON is http://data.nba.net/data/10s/prod/v1/calendar.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the _internal part at all (if you do you could still parse with your rawJson and class). Then you could do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> myData;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("http://data.nba.net/data/10s/prod/v1/calendar.json");
    string myJSON = "{" + rawJSON.Substring(rawJSON.IndexOf(@"""startDate"));
    myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(myJSON);
}
```

This would skip the _internal part and parse the rest as a Dictionary (although you might get as Dictionary I prefer string, string).

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of doing, I just didn't know how to do it with JSON. It worked perfectly!!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe javascript is better equipped if converting the file once by hand would suffice. Chances are you might need a more automatic approach.

```
// Load your JSON in variable x
var x = { "someOtherProperty": { etc:true }, "20171017": 2, "20171018": 11, "20171019": 3, "20171020": 10, "20171021": 11, "20171022": 3, "20171023": 8, "20171024": 6 }
x.games = []   // create an array that will hold the converted values.
for (key in x){
    // Some regex testing if the current property is a date
    if (/[2][0][01][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]/.test(key)){
        x.games.push({ date: key, gameCount: x[key] }); // Put the new object in an actual array
        delete x[key] // Delete the old value
    }
}
```

This would result in the following JSON where the array is nicely populated:

```
x = { 
     "someOtherProperty": { etc:true },
     "games":[{"date":"20171017","gameCount":2},{"date":"20171018","gameCount":11},{"date":"20171019","gameCount":3},{"date":"20171020","gameCount":10},{"date":"20171021","gameCount":11},{"date":"20171022","gameCount":3},{"date":"20171023","gameCount":8},{"date":"20171024","gameCount":6},{"date":"20171025","gameCount":10}]
}
```

Comment: I know this wont be the solution youre hoping to see. Hoping to spark someone that can convert this code into the newtonsoft.json C# way of approaching this.

Answer (score 0):

Given all the comments, particularly one that skips deserializing to some POCO, you could do something like this:

```
//Dependency JSON.Net

var obj = JObject.Parse(your_sample_json_string);
foreach (var t in obj)
{           
    DateTime d;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(t.Key, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", d.ToShortDateString(), t.Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10/17/2017 = 2
10/18/2017 = 11
10/19/2017 = 3
10/20/2017 = 10
10/21/2017 = 11
10/22/2017 = 3
10/23/2017 = 8
10/24/2017 = 6
10/25/2017 = 10
```

Improve as needed/necessary. Hth ~